# Classifying duration as <1, 1-2, 2-3, or >3 years

Tags: datetime, vb.net

How can I refactor this method to look cleaner and free from 2 `If` statements?

```
If NullableDate.HasValue Then
    Dim DayCount As Integer = (DateTime.Now.Date - NullableDate.Value).TotalDays
    Dim positive As Boolean = DayCount >= 0
    dim TimeLenght as Integer

    If positive Then
        If DayCount <= 364 Then
            TimeLenght = CustomEnum.LessThanOneYear
        ElseIf DayCount >= 365 And DayCount <= 729 Then
            TimeLenght = CustomEnum.BetweenOneAndTwoYears
        ElseIf DayCount >= 728 And DayCount <= 1094 Then
            TimeLenght = CustomEnum.BetweenTwoAndThreeYears
        Else
            TimeLenght = CustomEnum.ThreeYearsPlus
        End If
    End If
Else
    TimeLenght = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Why? Using two `If` statements looks reasonable here. I feel like we're missing the bigger context. Please clarify your question and the purpose of the code. Personally, I would prefer to see *the entire function or sub* as well.

Comment: Understood. The contents of this code were part of a method. I extracted it. I was just thinking if this could be accomplished in another shorter way. But Thanks. It was an attempt.

Comment: We'd be happy to review it if you post all of your code and explain the problem you're solving. I have several ideas, but won't answer until I have enough information to determine what is best.

Comment: My question was to reduce the lines of code, and move away from too many if and elseifs, and writing minimal code. I agree My question might be vague at this moment. Do you suggest closing the question ?

Comment: I suggest clarifying your question so you can get an answer. =;)-

Comment: I might be missing the point. Can I ask if this is a stackoverflow question versus, Code review. When is the code Review board ideally used.

Comment: Check out our help center and meta. This question is on topic here, but needs clarification if I'm going to answer it. Please see my earlier comment. I'm not going to answer without enough information to confidently recommend a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your requirements are open ended it's difficult to do this without atleast one `if` statement.  However I think you'll find it much more concise to use Integer division to convert `DayCount` to the enum value:

```
If positive Then
    If Daycount > 1094 Then
        TimeLenght = CustomEnum.ThreeYearsPlus
    Else
        TimeLenght = [Enum].Parse(GetType(CustomEnum), (Daycount \ 365).ToString)
    End If
Else
    TimeLenght = Nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dump the positive variable. I also find it weird to set an integer to Nothing since it only accept numbers.

```
If DayCount < 0 Then
    TimeLength = 0
ElseIf DayCount <= 364 Then
    TimeLenght = CustomEnum.LessThanOneYear
ElseIf DayCount >= 365 And DayCount <= 729 Then
    TimeLenght = CustomEnum.BetweenOneAndTwoYears
ElseIf DayCount >= 728 And DayCount <= 1094 Then
    TimeLenght = CustomEnum.BetweenTwoAndThreeYears
Else
    TimeLenght = CustomEnum.ThreeYearsPlus
End If
```

Variable usually starts with a lower case. Properties start with an upper case.

Comment: Booyah! thanks. Totally missed that 'nothing'. I'll check the variable naming standards and practices.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Length is usually not spelled Lenght either.

This doesn't take into account leap years

I would use a Select Case.. I find it a lot more readable and editable.. Since it short-circuits and ends as soon as the first matching condition is found you don't need to check to make sure daycount is BETWEEN two numbers, as long as it's less than the previous check (which evidently failed), it will be between the two...

So here it is with no "If's" (at least not explicit ones)

```
Select Case DayCount
    Case Is < 0
        TimeLength = 0
    Case is <= 365
        TimeLength = CustomEnum.LessThanOneYear
    Case is <= 729 
        TimeLength = CustomEnum.BetweenOneAndTwoYears
    Case is <= 1095
        TimeLength = CustomEnum.BetweenTwoAndThreeYears
    Case Else
        TimeLength = CustomEnum.ThreeYearsPlus
 End Select
```

And here's a second solution, again with no If's, but require carefully choosing the Enum's values

```
Enum CustomEnum
    LessThanOneYear = 0
    OneToTwoYears = 1
    TwoToThreeYears = 2
    OverThreeYears = 3
End Enum

Public Function GetTimeLength(days as integer) as CustomEnum
     'constrain the values to between 0 and 3 on the integer division 
     'of days/365
     Return Max(0, Min(days\365,3))
End function
```

I kinda like that one actually